# How do I combine two trigonometric waveforms that have the same $\omega t$ but different $\phi$

Tags: trigonometry

I am working on an applied math assignment of mine and there's this problem on waveform combination that is kinda tricky. My lecturer did a problem similar to this as an example. However, the example he did was simple as it only had the angular frequency and no phase shift.

Here is the problem:

> The current flowing in an AC circuit is defined by the following trigonometric waveform:
>   $$i=\cos(3t-1)-2\sin(3t+4)$$
>
> He wants us to combine those two waveforms into a simpler trigonometric waveform of the form 
>   $$i=\sin(\omega t+\phi) \quad\text{with}\quad \phi\geq 0$$

Here's my working:

using the identities $cos(A-B)=cos(A)cos(B)+sin(A)sin(B)$ and $sin(A+B)=sin(A)cos(B)+cos(A)sin(B)$

$$cos(3t)cos(-1)+sin(3t)sin(-1)-2[sin(3t)cos(-1)+cos(3t)sin(-1)]$$
$$0.5403023059cos(3t)-0.8414709848sin(3t)-2[0.5403023059sin(3t)-0.8414709848cos(3t)]$$
$$0.5403023059cos(3t)+1.68294197cos(3t)-0.8414709848sin(3t)-1.080604612sin(3t)$$
$$2.223244275cos(3t)-1.922075597sin(3t)$$
Using $Asin(\omega t + \phi)$:
$$A[sin(\omega t)cos(\phi)+cos(\omega t)sin(\phi)]$$
$$Asin(\omega t)cos(\phi)+Acos(\omega t)sin(\phi)$$
Equate coefficients:
$$2.223244275=Acos(\phi) eq1$$ 
$$(2.223244275)^2 = A^2sin^2(\phi) eq2$$
$$-1.922075597=Acos(\phi) eq3$$
$$(-1.922075597)^2=A^2cos^2(\phi) eq4$$
Now add eq2 and eq4:
$$(2.223244275)^2 + (-1.922075597)^2 = A^2cos^2(\phi)+A^2sin^2(\phi)$$
$$(2.223244275)^2 + (-1.922075597)^2 = A^2(cos^2(\phi)+sin^2(\phi))$$
$$(2.223244275)^2 + (-1.922075597)^2 = A^2$$
$$A=\sqrt{(2.223244275)^2+(-1.922075597)^2}$$
$$A=2.938909612$$
Now divide eq3 and eq1:
$$\frac{2.223244275}{-1.922075597}=\frac{Acos(\phi)}{Asin(\phi)}$$
$$\frac{2.223244275}{-1.922075597}=tan(\phi)$$
$$\phi = tan^-1 (\frac{2.223244275}{-1.922075597})$$
$$\phi = -0.8579234358 rads$$
Note that it is not in the domain so:
$$-0.8579234358 rads + 2\pi rads = 5.425261871 rads$$
$$\therefore \phi = 5.425261871 rads$$
So:
The simplified combined waveform is $2.938909612sin(3t+5.425261871)$.

That is the simplified form I came up with. However, the simplified form does not match with the original equation when graphed:
[image: Graph from desmos]
You can see clearly that it is out of phase with the original equation. What am I doing wrong? Is my approach correct? Please help!

Comment: For one thing, right at the start, it looks like you expanded $\sin(3t-1)$ instead of $\sin(3t+4)$.

Comment: @Blue damn! I just noticed that! Hahahaha..I've been working on my assignment for the whole day. This question I've been working on for 3 hours! For three hours I've been doing the wrong thing hahaha.

Comment: Also, since you're using the formula for $\cos(A-B)$, you should have $\cos(1)$ and $\sin(1)$ in your work, not $\cos(-1)$ and $\sin(-1)$. In any case, it'd be better to give names to those values to simplify all the arithmetic, then substitute the values in at the last step. (As a bonus, if you find a value has been in error, you only have to change it at the end.)

Comment: @Blue Noted! The signs confuse me all the time.

Comment: I find [this](https://dspguru.com/files/Sum_of_Two_Sinusoids.pdf) page quite useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the identities

$$\begin{align}
\cos(A-B) &= \cos A \cos B + \sin A \sin B \\
\sin(A+B) &= \sin A \cos B + \cos A \sin B
\end{align}$$

and defining
$$s_1 := \sin 1 \qquad c_1 := \cos 1 \qquad s_4 := \sin 4 \qquad c_4 := \cos 4$$

The initial equation becomes
$$\begin{align}
&\;c_1\cos 3t +s_1\sin 3t-2\left(\;c_4\sin 3t+s_4\cos 3t\;\right) \\
=&\;(s_1-2c_4)\sin 3t + (c_1-2s_4)\cos 3t \tag{1}
\end{align}$$
while the target equation (with an appended coefficient of $A$) is
$$A \sin \omega t \cos\phi + A\cos \omega t \sin\phi \tag{2}$$

Equating coefficients:
$$\begin{align}
A\cos\phi = s_1-2c_4 \tag{3} \\
A\sin\phi = c_1-2s_4 \tag{4}
\end{align}$$

Therefore,
$$\begin{align}
A^2 &= A^2\cos^2\phi + A^2\sin^2\phi \\
&= (s_1-2c_4)^2+(c_1-2s_4)^2 \\
&= \left(s_1^2+c_1^2\right) - 4\left(s_1 c_4+c_1 s_4\right) + 4\left(c_4^2+s_4^2\right) \\
&= 1 - 4\sin(1+4) + 4 \\
&= 5 - 4\sin 5 \\
\to A &= \sqrt{5-4\sin 5} = 2.972\ldots \tag{5}
\end{align}$$
and
$$
\tan\phi = \frac{A\sin\phi}{A\cos\phi}= \frac{c_1-2s_4}{s_1-2c_4}
\quad\to\quad \phi = \arctan\frac{\cos 1-2\sin 4}{\sin 1 - 2\cos 4} = 0.7628\ldots \tag{6}$$

Thus, we have

> $$2.972\ldots\cdot\sin(3t+0.7628\ldots) \tag{$\star$}$$

Comment: Thanks for that! Very helpful! I have one last question. 2.972 is the amplitude of the wave. Does that imply that it is the maximum current in the circuit?

Comment: I have no idea. I'm a mathematician, not an electrical engineer. :)

Comment: Haha! I'll do more research then. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Find the amplitude and phase shift of
\begin{equation}
y=a\cos(\omega t+\phi_1)+b\sin(\omega t+\phi_2)\tag{1}
\end{equation}

Notice that
\begin{eqnarray}
\omega t+\phi_1&=&\omega\left(t+\frac{\phi_1+\phi_2}{2\omega}\right)-\frac{\phi_2-\phi_1}{2}\\
\omega t+\phi_2&=&\omega\left(t+\frac{\phi_1+\phi_2}{2\omega}\right)+\frac{\phi_2-\phi_1}{2}
\end{eqnarray}

So if we make the substitutions
\begin{eqnarray}
T&=&t+\frac{\phi_1+\phi_2}{2\omega}\\
\phi&=&\phi_2-\phi_1
\end{eqnarray}
we can rewrite equation $(1)$ in a symmetric form as
\begin{equation}
y=a\cos\left(\omega T-\frac{\phi}{2}\right)+b\sin\left(\omega T+\frac{\phi}{2}\right)\tag{2}
\end{equation}

Note that

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{dy}{dT}&=&b\omega\cos\left(\omega T+\frac{\phi}{2}\right)-a\omega\sin\left(\omega T-\frac{\phi}{2}\right)\\
\frac{d^2y}{dT^2}&=&-a\omega^2\cos\left(\omega T-\frac{\phi}{2}\right)-b\omega^2\sin\left(\omega T+\frac{\phi}{2}\right)\\
\end{eqnarray}
Therefore, we get the differential equation
\begin{equation}
\frac{d^2y}{dT^2}+\omega^2y=0\\
\end{equation}
which has solution
\begin{eqnarray*}
y&=&y(0)\cos(\omega T)+\frac{y^\prime(0)}{\omega}\sin(\omega T)\\
&=&\left[a\cos\left(\frac{\phi}{2}\right)+b\sin\left(\frac{\phi}{2}\right)\right]\cos(\omega T)+
\left[b\cos\left(\frac{\phi}{2}\right)+a\sin\left(\frac{\phi}{2}\right)\right]\sin(\omega T)
\end{eqnarray*}

Now let
\begin{equation}
\psi=\arctan\left(\frac{a\cos\left(\frac{\phi_2-\phi_1}{2}\right)+b\sin\left(\frac{\phi_2-\phi_1}{2}\right)}{b\cos\left(\frac{\phi_2-\phi_1}{2}\right)+a\sin\left(\frac{\phi_2-\phi_1}{2}\right)}\right)
\end{equation}

Noting that

\begin{equation}
\left[a\cos\left(\frac{\phi}{2}\right)+b\sin\left(\frac{\phi}{2}\right)\right]^2+\left[b\cos\left(\frac{\phi}{2}\right)+a\sin\left(\frac{\phi}{2}\right)\right]^2=a^2+b^2+2ab\sin(\phi)
\end{equation}
we have
\begin{eqnarray}
y&=&\sqrt{a^2+b^2+2ab\sin(\phi_2-\phi_1)}\,\sin(\omega T+\psi)\\
y&=&\sqrt{a^2+b^2+2ab\sin(\phi_2-\phi_1)}\,\sin\left(\omega t+\frac{\phi_1+\phi_2}{2}+\psi\right)
\end{eqnarray}
giving the resulting amplitude and phase shift.

For the particular variables in your exercise the result is

$$ y=2.97249005022\sin(3t+0.762832763) $$

Comment: Thanks for that sir! Your working seems complex. I see you have used some calculus in your working. I'm a first year engineering student and I'll be taking calculus in my second semester. Your working will come in handy in my calculus studies. Thanks once again.